# Swipe right on Xamarin.iOS with IOS 13 doesn't animate the effect

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ios13

I have Xamarin Native (iOS/Droid) app. In older iOS versions, navigating back to previous viewControllers can be done by swiping right with one animation that drags the current view for the screen. When updating to the newest iOS 13, this animation doesn't appear anymore. The ViewWillDissapper doesn't get called either.
What am i missing?

I already tried this changes:

```
this.ModalInPresentation = true;
this.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen;
NavigationController.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Enabled = true;
NavigationController.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Delegate = new MyGestureDelegate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app is using Xamarin Native with Mvvm Cross. Turns out that the mvvm cross package in version 4.4 don't support iOS 13, and updating it to 5.7 solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 13 , you can set that in the ***previous ViewController*** as follow :

```
UIViewControllerSecond viewControllerSecond = new UIViewControllerSecond();
viewControllerSecond.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen;
viewControllerSecond.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.FlipHorizontal;
PresentViewController(viewControllerSecond, true, null);
```

Then in ***second ViewController*** just `DismissModalViewController(true);` when back .

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer swipeGesture = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer();
swipeGesture.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right;
swipeGesture.AddTarget(() => { Console.WriteLine("-swipe-to-right-"); DismissViewController(true, null); });
View.AddGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture);
```

Have a look at this effect , whether it is needs .

[image]

Comment: Thank's, but it didn't work, it seems that Xamarin with IOs 13, using dismissViewController() doesn't do anything

Comment: Hi, I tested it in iOS 13 , and it works . You can share the full code about navigation between two viewcontrollers .

Comment: Hi again, i know it works on iOS 13, the thing is i'm working with Xamarin, which works with Viewmodels, these fire up the viewcontrollers, I don't use the presentViewController method because it will lose the multiplatform aspect. The only way iOS lets em close one viewController is using NavigationController.PopViewController(animated);

Comment: @AdriaAlabau It depends on how to navigate to next controller (Model Navigation / NavigationControll Navigation ). If using `NavigationController.PushViewController(new UIViewControllerSecond(), true);` then you just can use `NavigationController.PopViewController(animated)` . However , here I use `PresentViewController(viewControllerSecond, true, null);` 
 or `PresentModalViewController(new UIViewControllerSecond(), true);` then I can `DismissViewController(true, null);` . Having a check with this whether work.